# Контроль доступа Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, access-control

В шаблоне yii2 advanced по дефолту сделан AccessControl в бэкэнд части

```
 'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                        'allow' => true,
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout', 'index','view','update','delete','word','confirmplatform','moderation-questionnaire','moderation-questionnaire-detail','cancelplatform','resend-email'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['admin','moderator'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
```

Как видно из правил, доступ в админку разрешён только `admin` и `moderator`.

Меня смущает то что если попытаться залогиниться в админку под аккаунтом с ролью `user` то yii пускает внутрь, экшен `login` отрабатывает. Только на экране мы видим 403 ошибку доступа.

Как сделать так чтобы при вводе "неправильных" аккаунтов просто перебрасывало на форму авторизации в админку с выводом ошибки?

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol#$denyCallback-detail
думаю тут ваше решение

Comment: @binliz ничего не понял , но очень интересно

Comment: Вам нужно проверять доступ во время авторизации. Не пускать в админку обычных пользователей, зачем же вы их пускаете?

Answer (score 0):

Надо заглянуть в AccessControl и посмотреть его поведение, когда доступ ограничен (когда 403 ошибка появляется). Затем создать свой бихевиор и унаследоваться от AccessControl. Переопределить тот метод, который отдает 403 ошибку, когда доступ запрещен и добавлять там в сессию ошибку, затем редиректить куда надо.

Как по мне, так 403 это корректная ошибка, если нет доступа.

Answer (score 0):

Так чтобы было понятно:

```
'access' => [
    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
            'allow' => true,
        ],
        [
            'actions' => ['logout', 'index','view','update','delete','word','confirmplatform','moderation-questionnaire','moderation-questionnaire-detail','cancelplatform','resend-email'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['admin','moderator'],
        ],
    ],
    'denyCallback' => function($rule, $action) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('info', 'ACCESS DENIDED!!!');
        return $action->controller->redirect('login');
    },
],
```

Comment: или вобще вывалить ошибку:
                     throw new ForbiddenHttpException(Yii::t('yii', 'You are not allowed to perform this action.'));

Comment: Получаю вот эту ошибку теперь Call to undefined method Closure::allows()

Comment: Ну так я ошибся а вы прям так и скопировали, вынесите denyCallback на уровень выше: class, rules, denyCallback должны быть на одном уровне